# How to deserialize JSON response using @JsonProperty?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have this object which is converted into following format but it does not wrap it properly.

```java
@JsonProperty("code")
private String code;
@JsonProperty("message")
private String msg;
@JsonProperty("assign")
private SomeVO someVO;
//getter, setters
```

to this format:

```
{
"status": {
     "code": $value, 
     "message": $value
},
"data":{
   "assign" {
    "schemaLayoutFileName" : $value
    "dataStoreTargetLocationText" : $value
       }
   }

}
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you have defined does not match the JSON you want to parse. Try the following design (if the class attributes names match the JSON properties names, you won't need [`@JsonProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html)):

```java
public class Foo {

    private Status status;
    private Data data;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class Status {

    private String code;
    private String value;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class Data {

    private Assign assign;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class Assign {

    private String schemaLayoutFileName;
    private String dataStoreTargetLocationText;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Thanks Saved my day!!

Comment: Hey @Cássio Mazzochi Molin what if we want change the name of the object such as assign dynamically?

Comment: @omkomawar If I understand you question, you want to have a JSON property called `assignDynamically` instead of `assign`. In this situation, you could use `@JsonProperty("assignDynamically") private Assign assign;`.

Comment: that i know but how do you change that string dynamically at runtime based on the assigned object

Comment: @omkomawar So you could try a `Map`. Something like `private Map<String, Object> assign;` or `private Map<String, Assign> assign;`. You also may need a constructor with `@JsonCreator`.